# ReactJS filestream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, filestream

Does ReactJS allowed to do streamwriter and streamreader? Or using file-system to create .txt file?

I've task that should convert string to .txt file from ReactJS, but it is possible? I've tried many ways but nothing works such as:

`var fs = required('fs');
var file = fs.createStreamwriter('output.txt');
file.write('Hello World')
file.end();`

But getting error fs.CreateStreamWriter is not a function.

I'm using Web Api as its server. Or shall i using its file-system in Web Api?

Sorry writing on smartphone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
const exportText = (title, data) => {
    // Create link and download
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    link.download = `${title}.txt`;
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```